# parse nested json with nested key Information preserved

Tags: python, json, parsing

Consider the JSON data as below:

```
{
  "postdata": {
    "items": [
      {
        "productid1": "ZPB-3166", 
        "quantity1": 1
      }, 
      {
        "productid2": "ZPB-1", 
        "quantity2": 1
      }
    ], 
    "xyz": 1
  }
}
```

I need to parse this nested JSON to have key value pair. But i need to preserve the information of nested JSON. for example i need to have

```
postdata_items_productid=ZPB-3166 postdata_items_quantity=1 ... postdata_items_xyz=1
```

How can I implement this in Python?

I have tried following code but it only parse the keyvalue pair and the nested key information is lost.

```
import json
data=u'''{"postdata" :{"items":[{"productid":"ZPB-3166","quantity":1},{"productid":"ZPB-1","quantity":1},{"productid":"ZPB-2","quantity":2},{"productid":"ZPB-3","quantity":3}],"xyz":1}}'''
jsondata=json.loads(data)
def _parse_json(dictionary,parse_data):
        for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                _parse_json(value,parse_data)
            elif isinstance(value,list):
                for item in value:
                    if isinstance(item,dict):
                        _parse_json(item,parse_data)
            else:
                parse_data.append((key,value))
        return parse_data
parse_data=[]
final_data=_parse_json(jsondata,parse_data)
print final_data
```

The result of the code is [(u'quantity', 1), (u'productid', u'ZPB-3166'), (u'quantity', 1), (u'productid', u'ZPB-1'), (u'quantity', 2), (u'productid', u'ZPB-2'), (u'quantity', 3), (u'productid', u'ZPB-3'), (u'xyz', 1)] but what is need is postdata_items_productid, postdata_items_xyz, etc in keys instead of productid or xyz.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " it only parse the keyvalue pair and the nested key information is lost." No information should be lost except for maybe order.

Comment: The result of the code is [(u'quantity', 1), (u'productid', u'ZPB-3166'), (u'quantity', 1), (u'productid', u'ZPB-1'), (u'quantity', 2), (u'productid', u'ZPB-2'), (u'quantity', 3), (u'productid', u'ZPB-3'), (u'xyz', 1)]
 but what is need is postdata_items_productid, postdata_items_xyz, etc in keys instead of productid or xyz.

Comment: Post that *in the question* not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Check out [flatten_json](https://medium.com/@amirziai/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10#.oop3susfq). The difference in output from what you have, which may actually be a feature you want, is flatten_json does not lose the index of the elements in nested lists. Therefore, you are able to completely reconstruct a flattened object (which you would be unable to do otherwise).

If you really need a custom solution, you can likely inspect the source code and use that to derive your own custom solution.

```
import json
from flatten_json import flatten_json
text = #...
print flatten_json(json.loads(text))
```

Output:

> {'postdata_items_0_quantity1': '1', 'postdata_xyz': '1', 'postdata_items_1_quantity2': '1', 'postdata_items_0_productid1': 'ZPB-3166', 'postdata_items_1_productid2': 'ZPB-1'}